# Calculating the mean value for a variable in an array for a set value for another variable

Tags: numpy, mean

I am looking to calculate the mean temperature at a range of depths (so the mean temperature at 2m, then 3m, etc), so that I am in the end able to create plot of mean temperature against depth. Temperature is one column in an array and depth is another column. Since there are a range of depths (from 2m to > 200m) I don't want to manually type out code for each depth, so I was wondering how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
temperature = data['Temperature']
depth = data['Depth']

meantemp = np.mean(temperature)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Are you using pandas or just numpy?

Comment: I've just been using numpy. I can't for security reasons, but it's in a format similar to:

Comment: In one column, temperature values 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 8.0, 8.5. And then in the depth column something like 2, 5, 8, 12, 2.

Answer (score -2):

download/copy and save the code found [here](http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp) as (f.i.) grouping.py:

then write:

```
from grouping import group_by
print group_by(depth.round(0)).mean(temperature)
```

Comment: that's a quick downvote; too much work to download and save the code?

Comment: -1. Answers should at least make some attempt to explain the solution rather than throwing code at the OP. Also what happens for anyone in the future who wants to use this answer if your pastebin link has been lost? Answers should be self-contained with optional links to relevant documentation, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to download the code as I am at work and they have restrictions on internet downloads, although I do appreciate the offer for help.

Comment: the pastebin link does not have an expiration; its no less permanent than anything else on the internet. there is no need to download anything; you can simple copy the raw code paste and insert it in your own. if additional explanation is required, id be happy to give it, but fwiw; this is the simplest solution to your problem which 'just works'.

Comment: That link is extremely long, (over 30,000 characters). Seems a little excessive to me :(

Comment: its the same ctrl-A ctrl-C motion regardless of the character count. No doubt it would be preferable to sculpt this into a numpy pull request; but until someone takes the effort to do so, I contend that this is the most convenient answer to the original question.